# Letter Altering Code

Tags: python

This script takes a sentence and encodes it. The code takes each letter in a given word and bumps it up in the alphabet by the length of the word.  So "cat" becomes "fwd", "small" becomes "xrfqq", and "small cat" becomes "xrfgg fwd".

I wanted to see if there was anything I should have done differently or if ya'll had some suggestions for improvements.

```
#Letter altering code

alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j",
        "k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t",
        "u","v","w","x","y","z"]

textIn= ""

while textIn.lower != 'q':
    textIn = input("Type a sentence to be translated ('q' to quit).\n"\
               ).lower()
    textOut = ""

if textIn == 'q':
    break
else:
    for word in textIn.split():
        newWord = ""
        for char in word:
            if char in alphabet:
                pos = alphabet.index(char)
                newPos = (pos + len(word))%26 
                newChar = alphabet[newPos]
                newWord += newChar

            else:
                newWord += char

        textOut += newWord + " " 

print(textOut)
```

Comment: I think you want codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is your specific question? With a naked eye I can see you're missing parenthesis in `while textIn.lower != 'q'`.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty good.

`alphabet` is [**`string.ascii_lowercase`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase)

`textIn.lower` should be `textIn.lower()`

[**`break`**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) should only be used in a loop. You want [**`pass`**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements), which means 'do nothing'.

The loop adding the new character to the new word is clear. I like it. There are other terser ways to do it, though, which are more pythonic and can still be as clear.

Comment: I was unaware of [string.ascii_lower] and [pass]. Thank you for bringing them to my attention